# Invalid Clarifai API key or pair?

Tags: python, jupyter, clarifai

On Clarifai community, I created a new project and generated a new API key with scope of all. When I try to input my key as an environmental variable, I'm unable to use it. I've posted the code, warning, and error below. Trying to utilize the ClarifaiAPIImageExtractor...

```
from pliers.filters import FrameSamplingFilter
from pliers.extractors import ClarifaiAPIImageExtractor, merge_results

video = join(get_test_data_path(), 'video', 'small.mp4')

# Sample 2 frames per second
sampler = FrameSamplingFilter(hertz=2)
frames = sampler.transform(video)

api_key = os.environ.get('CLARIFAI_API_KEY')

ext = ClarifaiAPIImageExtractor(api_key=api_key)
results = ext.transform(frames)
df = merge_results(results, )
df
```

generates the following warning:

```
WARNING:root:b'GET https://api.clarifai.com/v2/models FAILED(1659415936.709821). status_code: 401, reason: Unauthorized, error_code: 11008, error_description: Invalid API key or Invalid API key/application pair, error_details: Invalid format of key.\n >> Python client 2.6.2 with Python 3.7.12 on darwin\n >> GET https://api.clarifai.com/v2/models\n >> REQUEST(1659415936.709821) {\n  "page": 1,\n  "per_page": 20\n}\n >> RESPONSE(1659415936.709821) {\n  "status": {\n    "code": 11008,\n    "description": "Invalid API key or Invalid API key/application pair",\n    "details": "Invalid format of key.",\n    "req_id": "1dd144af76c8fe7f2ae9a35a2204a079"\n  },\n  "models": []\n}'
0it [00:06, ?it/s]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you've used the wrong format of the API Key.
According to the Clarifai documentation, you need to authenticate this way:

```
# metadata = (('authorization', 'Key ' + 'YOUR_CLARIFAI_API_KEY_HERE'),)
# Yes, the word 'Key' appears in addition to the alphanumeric PAT or API Key
```

So, you need to provide the word 'Key' in addition to your API Key.

Try this:

```
api_key = os.environ.get('Key CLARIFAI_API_KEY_HERE')
```